# Logistic Regression, continuous feature is categorical

Tags: logistic, categorical-encoding

I'm using logistic regression for a simple binary classification.  I have a feature, x, and looks something like this

```
if x < 10 or x >= 20, then it tends to be class A
if 10 <= x < 20, then it tends to be class B
```

is the standard procedure to one hot encode this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to create two variables $Y$ and $Z$.  Code $Y$ 1 if $X\le10$ or $X\ge20$.  Then you'll create another variable $Z$ and code it 1 if $10\le X\lt20$, otherwise zeo.